# ObjectBox entities list in Android?

Tags: android, objectbox

How to receive in ObjectBox the list of entities? 
How to get for each entity the number of records and the size of the disk?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are docs that help you get started:
https://docs.objectbox.io/

Comment: I already use the ObjectBox and I want to estimate how much space each table takes. I do not find the answer to this question in this document. Please give me direct link.

Comment: That's highly dependent on your data. I'd suggest to just test it yourself.

Comment: The problem is that with frequent deletions and inserts, the ObjectBox directory grows rapidly. I would like to know what kind of tables this happens. By the way, I would like to have an analog SqlLite pragma pack.